# I switched from Godot 3, and i don't know what export(Resource) is in Godot 4

Tags: gdscript, godot4

I switched from Godot 3 to Godot 4 and was trying to make a platforming game.
I need the export(Resource) function, but it no longer exists/functions in the new Godot.
What's the equivalent of the function, but in Godot 4?

(language is GDScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `export` was never a function. It was a keyword. And instead of the `export` keyword, Godot 4 uses the `@export` annotation. You can find the syntax in [GDScript exports](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html#doc-gdscript-exports).

*There are other annotations, you might do good in reading about them in the official documentation: [annotations](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#annotations).*

---

And second, in Godot 4 the way a variable is exported is predicated on the declared type of the variable.

So what you would write in Godot 3 like this:

```
export(Resource) var variable_name:Resource
```

In Godot 4 would be like this:

```
@export var variable_name:Resource
```

---

Furthermore, chances are you don't want to export as `Resource` but as a more specific type, except Godot 3 didn't support exporting variables a custom `Resource` types (build-in types were fine). However that is no longer true in Godot 4, so you can use your custom `Resource` type:

```
@export var variable_name:CustomResourceClass
```